# Preventing BFAs in website login forms without Rate limiting, Captcha or Two factor authentication

Tags: brute-force

I have the problem that in my particular Content Management System (CMS), preventing BFAs in website login forms without Rate limiting, Captcha or Two factor authentication isn't ready out of box or requires development resources that at least to my current understanding I don't have or cannot afford.

The only other possible approach which comes to my mind is to *disable my public login form* and login through a web hosting control panel GUI instead, or from an SSH CLUI instead --- but I have no idea how this would be implementable in a CMS-particular/agnostic way.

How would you solve the problem I have presented?

Comment: Let me rephrase your question in the way I've understood it: Established approaches are too costly in terms of development resources for you to use. And that's why you want to invest resources to develop a different way which is not yet established. I would argue that developing your own way will be either significantly inferior or will actually be more costly than using established approaches.

Comment: But if this only about protecting only few path and accounts, like your own admin account: one can use features of the web server to add additional light-weight restrictions to specific path, like requiring basic authentication or a client certificate. Basic authentication can be sufficient against brute forcing providing a strong password is used. And client certificates protect against brute-force too and are also comfortable to use as long access is only needed from a few systems (which have these certificates installed).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich there might be an "established" way I never learned about, perhaps even easy to implement. I never heard about a "client certificate" before, for example.

Comment: Established approaches are the ones you've already mentioned, i.e. Captcha, rate limiting, 2FA ... . Note also that you can use some CDN providers like Cloudflare in front of your site - they offer various protections too. And what you can do depends highly on what to protect and what usability is required (more security commonly means less usability). And it is different if you want to protect just admin accounts or all users (in which case usually more usability is needed). And, it also depends on the CMS so it would be helpful to know what you actually want to use.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the relevant website is MediaWiki 1.34.2 based; Rate limiting there requires CMS-level caching which I currently prefer not to use. About Cloudflare; it's nice you mention this because I already get a nice package there with the mediation of my hosting provider and I utilize it to prevent DDoSs; I had no clue that it might help with BFAs, I should search for documentation about how.

Comment: I went through some CloudFlare community documents I found with `cloudflare brute force` on Google but none explains how CF (or any other security oriented CDN for that matter) prevents Brute Force Attacks; someone is most welcome to explain this in an answer if she or he want.

Comment: chances are if you use a web-hosting control panel you'll only be passing the buck to a different account on the same host (please specify what style of hosting service you're using) - as was already mentioned by Steffen Ullrich, requiring basic auth to access the login screen is a highly effective means of slowing down all the high-speed morons - you can even *'ess pee eeee ell ell' (ALL CAPITALS)* the password out in the prompt, so your users don't get too annoyed with you! another option- consider renaming the login page filename, and place the new url in a 400 error in the `.htaccess`.